# How do I add more than one function in my $(document).ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this and it works fine:

```
$(document).ready(
    highlightTableRow
);
```

but when I add a second function (see below) the second doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(
    highlightTableRow,
    attachClickLinkHandlerForRowLink
);
```

What's the correnct syntax for adding a second function to my ready function?  Thanks.

edit: add syntax errors. (eclipse)

```
$(document).ready(
    highlightTableRow();  **// error:Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Arguments**
    attachClickHandlerForRowLink();  **//error: Missing semicolon**
); **// error: Syntax error on token ")", delete this token**


var originalRowBackground;

function highlightTableRow(){
    $('[class^="contentRow"]:has(a)').live('mouseenter', enterRowFunction).live('mouseleave', exitRowFunction);
}

function enterRowFunction(){
    originalRowBackground = $(this).css('background-color');
    $(this).css({'background-color': "#EFE3FF", 'cursor': 'pointer'});
}

function exitRowFunction(){
    $(this).css({'background-color': originalRowBackground, 'cursor': 'pointer'});
}

function attachClickHandlerForRowLink(){
    $('[class^="contentRow"]:has(a)').live('click', clickRowLink);
}

function clickRowLink(){
    window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
}    **//error: Missing semicolon**
```

Comment: add parens () and semicolons ; after your function calls

Comment: All answers are same.. and they should be..

Comment: @AlphaMale you wouldn't believe it ... some answers was errata maximus ;) (now fixed... I hope...) 8D

Comment: @Evan That was the first thing I tried, but it doesn't work.  I'll update the original post for clarity to add error messages.

Comment: Thanks all.  Got it.  I missed the part about wrapping it in a function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you could do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    highlightTableRow();
    attachClickLinkHandlerForRowLink();
});
```

also you could change the `$(document).ready()` part into `$(function()` so you would get

```
$(function() {
    highlightTableRow();
    attachClickLinkHandlerForRowLink();
});
```

does the same only shorter

Comment: you win (were the quickest) :) +1

Comment: Congrats! well.. that was a hell of a race! ;D

Answer (score 4):

try like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    highlightTableRow();
    attachClickLinkHandlerForRowLink();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    highlightTableRow();
    attachClickLinkHandlerForRowLink();

});
```

Am I missing the point?

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use like this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    highlightTableRow();
    attachClickLinkHandlerForRowLink();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, sometimes the code function doesn't work perfectly for mey.

Answer (score 2):

`document.ready` takes a **function**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    highlightTableRow();
    attachClickLinkHandlerForRowLink();
});
```

Comment: shouldn't the first one just call attachClickLinkHandlerForRowLink?

Comment: +1 ... all of us have recieved votes... it would be silly if you don't get at least 2 as most of us! :D :D

Comment: @roXon - lol - your vote capped me for the day -- thanks!  so the next visitor should save his votes for someone who needs it :-P

Comment: heheh ;) thanks! (do you believe, answering the Q I stopped a second asking my self...'Is this guy kidding?' (the OP) :D)

Comment: @roXon - when I first read the question, I thought he was asking something completely different...I thought he wanted more than one document.ready section.  But yeah, wow.  jQuery is wonderfully awesome, but it's so easy to use that stuff like this crops up from time to time.

Comment: Yeah! right hahah, thought too was some new invention from the *jQ fancy scene* to crop the ready call :D